# use for_each and lambda to destroy a acclocated object

Tags: c++

I'm doing a exercise on c++ primer,using for_each and lambda to rewrite a member function.
the member function looks like this:

```
if (elements) {
    if (elements) {
        for (auto p = elements; p != first; p++) {
            alloc.destroy(p);
        }
        alloc.deallocate(elements, cap - elements);
    }//elements,first,cap are all pointer,alloc is static allocator<string> type.
```

and i rewrite it with for_each:

```
for_each(elements, first, [](string *ptr) {alloc.destroy(ptr); });
```

and it gives error like this in visual studio 2017:

```
"void main::<lambda_367d5ef0c506f20aa71a87bbe93ab079>::operator ()(_Ty *) const": Unable to convert parameter 1 from "_Ty" to "std::string*"
```

but if i write this,it works fine:

```
auto ptr= [](string *pr) {alloc.destroy(pr); };
auto p = elements;
while (p!=first)
{
    ptr(p++);
}
alloc.deallocate(elements, cap - elements);
```

someone please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functors in STL algorithms, including `for_each`, take an object as their argument, not an iterator. You are trying to pass an iterator (which is in your case a pointer) as the lambda's parameter. A fix:

```
for_each(elements, first, [](string& s) {alloc.destroy(&s); });
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but why does second one work fine? i don't understand

Comment: You have three attempts. The first one is great, the second one doesn't (and has the problem mentioned in the answer) and the third is also fine. The answer is that in the first and the third, you are passing in a pointer. And `for_each` does not pass in a pointer, it passes in a reference. This is because `for_each` works when the iterator being used isn't a pointer, like when you use it to iterate over a `map`.

Comment: Are you asking why your last code snippet works? Because there you pass a pointer argument to the lambda. `std::for_each()` expects you to pass the object itself.